# Change name of project to archive it, reusing the old name

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2012/2013. 
I want to "put away" a project and reuse its name. Say I have a project called ABC where development has been going on, but now I want to retire this version and call it ABC_Archive, and reuse the name ABC on a fresh project.
This need came about because a client is switching from old ASP code to .Net for their website. The new version will supplant the old, with no need to bring any of the old baggage, except the name. I realise I could name the new project something like ABC_DotNet, but I would rather keep the old name.
I can't find a way to do this except create a new ABC_Archive, populate it with the old code, destroy ABC, and recreate ABC with the new code. Of course this loses all the history of the original, but that is not a huge problem, since the last version is all that will be looked at anyway (I hope).
Please let me know if there is some other way, and I will buy you a cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ability (yet) to rename a Team Project in TFS.  I can make a couple of suggestions:

1) Keep the ABC Team Project, create root source control folder called Archive, and move all the code under there.

2) Clone the Team Project Collection, call the new TPC ABC_Archive (if there are other team projects in the collection you can delete all of them except ABC in the clone).  Then delete the ABC team project from your main TPC.  See here for more info on splitting/cloning a TPC: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think I shall have to try method 1 and see how the move goes.

Comment: #2 is a little overkill with a couple of problems I can see immediately. a) It could not be built again since we have only the one build server, and b) as more clients/projects switch we would end up with many collections. Originally I tried setting up a collection for each client, but ran into (a) above i.e. each collection needs its own build server. The good news is you do get a cookie, but it will have to transmitted one byte at a time!